# HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed error in admin log

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting a strange error in my newly deployed application in appengine. In the error log it tells me that PageRank, TwitterBot and a couple of others. I would guess this is due to these try to get data using ajax or another async service resulting in "same origin policy"-problem.

My question is does anyone know what these bots are trying to get? For example if pagerank (google page rank I would guess) can't get any info about my application would this effect my page rank. And anyone know what the twitterbot does? And if there is away to handle to provide a proper response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your RequestHandlers (I'm assuming you're using python with webapp from the tags on your earlier questions) aren't implementing a method for whichever request method the bots are using.  I'd guess they're HEAD requests, and you have no `head()` methods defined.

Comment: Thanks(again), yes I'm using python. I've never worked with other requests then GET/POST. HEAD only fetches headers right? But how to handle it in code? Just present it the same way as get?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to call your get() method, then throw away the body before responding; the response should be the same as for a get with an empty body.