# 405 Method Not Allowed The method POST is not allowed for this resource appengine facebook App

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, http-status-code-405

I'm doing an app on appengine and it works just fine there .I have the app's URL on facebook canvas url http://xx.appspot.com/yyy/ (with trailing slash) and when the app is called from http://apps.facebook.com/appname i get

> 405 Method Not Allowed The method POST is not allowed for this
>   resource.
>
> class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>       def get(self): #do stuff here
>       def post(self): pass
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>       ('/yyy/', MainHandler),
>       ('/',anotherHandler),
>
> ], debug=True  )

note : no such error in appengine log .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730032/http-error-405-method-not-allowed-error-in-admin-log, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=appengine+405+Method+Not+Allowed

Answer (score 7):

It's trying to make a POST to your app but you do not have a handler configured to receive it.

Where you have your `GET` handler:

```
 def get(self):
     dostuff
```

you also need to have a `POST` hander as well:

```
def post(self):
    dostuff
```

From what I remember when I last looked at this, it's probably trying to complete a step in the authorisation process or send you some data.

Comment: well, it won't write out "test" except to facebook when they come calling. Suggest you start with one of their working examples?

Answer (score 3):

Good Day !

It seems like I FINALLY  figured out what my problem was . I defined the post method in the application as Paul C(which is correct) has mentioned but I was still getting the same 405 error message . The reason was ,I didn't update the default version of the app that was running from the appengine dashboard & updated my app version.

please make sure which version of the app you are using if you have the same problem.
https://appengine.google.com/deployment?app_id=s~APP_ID&version_id=default:

I hope no one goes through this same experience I did.
Thanks all.