# webapp2 - how to post form data - app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

Having some trouble posting data from form and handling it with webapp2.

I'm not sure how to handle data from a form in webapp2 in general, including which page to post the data to with the form action.

My form is on the page '/schedule/create-consult'. and I'm initially testing submitting the first two fields to the same page (ie. first name and last name being posted to /schedule/create-consults).

My form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="/schedule/create-consult">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="first_name" />
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="last_name" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click the Save button I get the message:

**405 Method Not Allowed - The method POST is not allowed for this resource.**

My routes look like this

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/schedule', SchedulePage),
    ('/consults', ConsultsPage),
    ('/schedule/create-consult', CreateConsultPage),
    ('/consults/john-smith-030617-0930', JohnSmithPage)
], debug=True)
```

My handler for CreateConsultsPage looks like this

```
class CreateConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/create-consult.html')  
    self.response.out.write(template.render())
```

And my app.yaml is as follows:

```
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /css
   static_dir: css
 - url: /images
   static_dir: images
 - url: /js
   static_dir: js
 - url: /
   script: main.app
 - url: /schedule
   script: main.app
 - url: /consults
   script: main.app
 - url: /schedule/create-consult
   script: main.app
 - url: /consults/john-smith-030617-0930
   script: main.app

 libraries:
 - name: webapp2
   version: latest
 - name: jinja2
   version: latest
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [405 Method Not Allowed The method POST is not allowed for this resource appengine facebook App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346309/405-method-not-allowed-the-method-post-is-not-allowed-for-this-resource-appengin)

Comment: There should be an indentation between def get(self): and the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting the form using post method. You have to define the post function in your handler class to get the submitted form data. This will solve your problem.

```
class CreateConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/create-consult.html')  
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
        first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
        last_name = self.request.get('last_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to make a POST to your app but you do not have a handler configured to receive it.

Where you have your GET handler:

```
class CreateConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         dostuf
```

you also need to have a POST hander as well:

```
class CreateConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        dostuff
```