# Referencing an HTML button to Python Script

Tags: python, html, function, reference

My objective in this program is to store information in a database. My problem is that I'm trying to link a button from my HTML page by using a Python script. My instructor told us that it **must** be written in Python. Any Libraries that support Python 2.7 would work for me.

```
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from models import Note
import webapp2

import jinja2
import os

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_env.get_template('./main.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

class InfoHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        note = Note(img = images.Image(photo.usr_img))


class Note(ndb.Model):
    def get(self):
        usr_img = ndb.BlobProperty()
        desc = ndb.StringProperty()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

```
<html>
    <head lang = "en">
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class = "container">
                    <h1>If this is an emergency, upload a photo and provide a short description.</h1>
                    <div id = "upload" >
                        <label for = "img">Upload image:</label>
                        <input type = "file" name = "pic" accept = "image/*"/>
                        <label for = "desc">Description:</label>
                        <input type = "text" />
                        <input type = "submit" href = "{{ submit_data }}"/>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I'm a noob in Python and I'm taking on a tough problem for class. Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Python and HTML are separate, so you can't explicitly link them. But you could create a HTML form that sends data to your python backend.

Comment: How do I do that? If you have references too, it would definitely help.

Comment: I'm not on a computer at the moment, so have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298851/webapp2-how-to-post-form-data-app-engine#42336812

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I keep getting this error:

`INFO     2018-08-16 01:18:19,336 module.py:880] default: "GET /?authuser=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 773

INFO     2018-08-16 01:18:25,671 module.py:880] default: "GET /main.py?pic=20180410_004311.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 154`